# Easier multiple value changes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really in need of this one, because I cann't manually type loads of options for admin panel. Hence I need a quick way to fetch each input/select and add value as I want.

Here's looong sample for one option field:

```
$("select[name=big_proceed]").val("true");
$("select[name=proceed_action]").val("");
$("input[name=choice_premium]").val("Premium <span>Code</span>");
$("input[name=big_proceed_pts]").val("");

$("#settings_proceed input, #settings_proceed select").each(function () {
    databaseData($(this));
});
```

I thought something like this may work but apparently I was wrong. Here's sample:

```
$("#settings_proceed :input").each(function () {
    $(this)
        .eq(0).val("true")
        .eq(1).val("")
        .eq(2).val("Premium <span>Code</span>")
        .eq(3).val("");

    databaseData($(this));
});
```

Any suggestions for me ?

Comment: there is no easy way to do what you what .. because there is no pattern .. each field is just of different value ..

Comment: Well there must be a way to target each input and select and change it's value by typing it manually... I just don't know how to target them properly. No ideas why .eq() won't work.

Comment: You know what would help? HTML, with precise instructions as to which elements you want to select, and what, precisely, you want to do.

Comment: @DavidThomas , Well since it's used in Admin Panel for database changes, attaching the ID to each input or select element is still lot of work and again it is same as targeting the name of it. So I don't see whats your exact point. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @NenaddvL it's still as messy as the first way, but the first way is clearer at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

> **.eq(index):** Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Hence your second example doesn't work as intended because `$(this)` only matches one element (that's the intention behind the `.each()`). You could rewrite the code like so:

```
var values = ["true", "", "Premium <span>Code</span>", ""];
$("#settings_proceed :input").each(function(i){
    $(this).val(values[i]);
    databaseData($(this));
});
```

However, this approach makes the code hard to read and error-prone because it assumes a fixed order of the HTML elements (what if you change the order of the input fields but forget to adjust the JS accordingly?). So you really should "manually" add IDs to your input elements and select them by their ID and not their index.

As @David Thomas pointed out, some sample HTML would be quite helpful here, but without knowing any further details of what you're trying to do I'd suggest the following:

```
var values = {
    big_proceed: "true",
    proceed_action: "",
    choice_premium: "Premium <span>Code</span>",
    big_proceed_pts: ""
};

$.each(values, function(key, value){
    $("#settings_proceed").find("[name='"+key+"']").val(value);
    databaseData($(this));
});
```

That way you can neatly define all the values in one object and let jQuery safely do the rest.